# How unordered_map cause sigsegv

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

**EDIT: solved, I know how but I don't understand why.**

I changed `variables` declaration from

```
tr1::unordered_map<int,T> variables;
```

to

```
unordered_map<int,T> variables;
```

and it's work fine.

*If you know why please write it in the answers.*

I have a very large program, so I don't know which code I should bring here.

There is abstract class, that inherits with derived class. 
The abstract have `unordered_map<int,int>` (template) as private member, and public method `insert(int,int)`.

The derived class use the base class `insert` method to insert elements to the `unordered_map<int,int>` container,

The first `int` uses like counter and start with 0. The first eleven insert elements going O.K. but in the 12th element I get sigsegv,and fault in `struct equal_to` at stl_function.h(209).

In the debugger I have saw that the unordered_map's bucket_count equal to 11, maybe it's clue for something.

My compiler is gcc 4.6.1.

Maybe you can write in general what **can** cause sigsegv in `unordered_map.insert`?

Thank you, and sorry about my poor English.

I will bring specific code, if I know which.

EDIT:
This is the `insert` method:

```
virtual void Insert(int arrayPlace, T value)
{
    if (!isReadOnly)
    {            
        if (IsValueDataValid(value))
        {
           variables[arrayPlace] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw 2;
        }            
    }
    else
    {
        throw 4;
    }
};
```

The declaration is:

```
tr1::unordered_map<int,T> variables;
```

The sigsegv happend when `arrayPlace`==11, And it dosn't matter what `value` equal.

Comment: You are using the container incorrectly but without the code that causes the problem, no one can answer this question.  If there is a lot of code, start reducing the problem to the minimum required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Assume that [it's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) unless you can prove otherwise.

Comment: The error lies elsewhere, in your code. There's nothing wrong with the unordered map as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the question is very simple: if you use the code correctly, no segmentation fault will be created by `std::unordered_map`! So the question becomes: what are typical user errors when using `std::unordered_map`? Off-hand I would think immediately of three issues:

1. The objects are placed into the map as values. That is, the objects need be copyable or movable. That is, I would investigate whether the type `T` you got correctly implements copy construction. In particular, you want to pay attention to the copy constructor if it isn't in the class but the class has an assignment operator or a destructor.
2. The hash key computed isn't really a hash key but something possibly depending on the location of the object. This would cause funny behavior because the object move to some extend (although once they are inserted they stay put).
3. Similar to the previous issue, the equality operation isn't really an equality operation. The unordered map needs the equality operator to determine if two objects with the same hash code are indeed the same.

Given that the key is an `int` and the hash code and equality are provided I would concentrate on the first issue. That is, I would concentrate on this once I have proved that the use of the `std::unordered_map` is indeed the problem: the segmentation violation may also quite easily result from things being messed up earlier. For example, something may have overwritten memory or deleted memory the wrong way, etc. Tools like purify or valgrind can help finding these issue. In any case, you want to boil down the program to a minimal crashing example. Typically I find that the issue becomes obvious in the process.

Comment: Do you mean that even simple int variable (that entered) need copy constructor (or reference to exist variable) for work fine with std::unordered_map?

Comment: Well, conceptually, yes. However, the built-in types have all the relevant operations [implicitly] defined. Similarly, there is a working hash and equality defined for them. If the type `T` also happens to be an `int` the problem is **not** with the code you posted but somewhere else. What actually causes the problem is harder to detect. From you error description I would assume that memory gets overwritten somewhere but it can be something else entirely. That the problem shows up in `std::unordered_map<int, int>' is just by chance.

Comment: So it's can't be because the `T value` it's out of scope when the method ended?

Comment: No: all of the containers in the standard C++ library keep a copy of the values you give them. If you `T` is a pointer or a class type which contains e.g. a pointer you may end up with stale pointers in the container. However, you said that `T` is `int`.

Comment: Well, it's nevertheless `int`. Thank you, Now I have to think...

Comment: please see my edit. Maybe you can explain?

Comment: Without tracking things down it is essentially impossible to say. I doubt that `tr1::unordered_map` has blatant error causing it to only allow insertion of 11 elements. The two different maps may be implemented entirely different (e.g. one may use a pool for its nodes while the other does not), causing one version to avoid the problem encountered by the other. It is also possible that some code is used which doesn't match up between library and header. The error you observed lays somewhere but where is impossible to tell (with the information given).

Comment: For me, it was a faulty move constructor for T using `unordered_map::insert( std::make_pair< T, U >( ... ) )`.